# Cannot find PhpMyAdmin on NGINX with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

I installed Wordpress and PhpBB on Ubuntu 16.04 with NGINX. Now for some reason I have to access my MySQL GUI to delete some users. But I am not able to find Phpmyadmin at mydomain/Phpmyadmin.

Has WordPress disabled access to it?

Comment: Was `phpMyAdmin` there, and did you use it, before installing WordPress

Comment: Hi, Welcome To SO, WordPress has nothing to with phpmyadmin, was phpmyadmin installed before installing wordpress?

Comment: Basically if you didnt install `phpMyAdmin` it is not installed. It is not part of Ubuntu or Wordpress. [maybe this will help you](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04)